# Spring Cloud Gateway: Request headers seems to be cached when using route level filters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour when using filters with Spring Cloud Gateway, given the following configuration sample:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringCloudConfig {

  @Bean
  public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
        .route(r -> r.path("/sample/v1/api")
            .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/sample", "").addRequestHeader("route-random",
                (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "")
                .filter(new AddHeaderCustomFilter().apply(new HeaderConfig(
                    "filter-random", (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + ""))))
            .uri("http://localhost:8085"))
        .build();
  }
}
```

If I perform two or more dinstict requests to "/sample/v1/api" the "route-random" and "filter-random" headers will always have the same value i.e. the random value generated for the first request.
Using a Global filter instead:

```
@Component
public class CustomGlobalFilter {

  @Bean
  public GlobalFilter globalFilter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
      exchange.getRequest().mutate()
          .header("global-random", (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "").build();
      return chain.filter(exchange);
    };
  }
}
```

The "global-random" header seems to be effectly random for each request.
Can someone explain why the value seems to be cached when using route level filters and a possible solution instead of using global filters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I think this is because the gateway matches the same requests based on params and url.

`AddRequestHeader is aware of URI variables used to match a path or host. URI variables may be used in the value and will be expanded at runtime.`

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#the-addrequestheader-gatewayfilter-factory